# Can't figure out why brew version of python is not being used

Tags: python, homebrew

In a new shell:

`brew install python` outputs:

```
Warning: python-2.7.5 already installed
```

`brew link python` outputs:

```
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5
To relink: brew unlink python && brew link python
```

`echo $PATH` outputs:

```
/Users/captbaritone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/captbaritone/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/captbaritone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/captbaritone/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/usr/texbin:/opt/local/bin
```

And yet `which python` still outputs:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
```

And `python --version` still outputs:

```
Python 2.7.1
```

**Here is a lead:**

`ls -l /usr/local/bin/python` outputs:

```
ls: /usr/local/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong, or what else I could try?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean ``python``, not ``php``? ``which`` won't tell you if it's a link; you need to run ``ls -l /usr/local/bin/python`` to see the link target (if any). What does ``brew link python`` say?

Comment: @Bogdan This get's me closer, but I'm still not sure what's wrong. As my edits say, `/usr/local/bin/python` does not seem to exist despite brew thinking it's linked.

Comment: I just noticed, does ``which`` really give you a path without the leading slash? If it's not a typo, it's very strange.

Comment: @bogdan ugh, another typo. Thanks for keeping my tired brain honest.

Comment: Did you try to relink it? It's strange that ``which`` points to a non-existent path, I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: @Bogdan I did (before and again just to check), no change in the return of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python`.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't link python properly. If you type `brew install python` on your terminal, it may output as *Warning: python-2.7.5 already installed, it's just not linked*.

If then, you need to link your python install by typing `brew link python`. If you face any conflict because of some earlier site-packages, just type as `brew link --overwrite python`.

Now it should work fine.